# How can I call on chain module without it's source code?

Tags: move-lang, sui

I want to call other module's function in my contract, but I haven't it's source code, just can see it's bytecode onchain;

In sodility has interface contract, and just need a proto (interface), then can call any contract even has no source code as fllow:

So how to do it in sui move?

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract InfoFeed {

    function info() payable returns (uint ret)；
}

contract Consumer {
    function deposit() payable returns (uint){
        return msg.value;
    } 

    function left() constant returns (uint){
         return this.balance;
    }

    function callFeed(address addr) returns (uint) { 
        return InfoFeed(addr).info.value(1).gas(8000)(); 
        // here i no need to get source code for InfoFeed implements, and can call it with address 
    }
}
```

Comment: Not at this time

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you only have the modules bytecode and still want to call a function from it means that **you really understand what that code does**. If it is the case then you must also have **understanding of what parameters it takes**.

With above assumption you can, very easily, call any public function from any already deployed package by updating two files:

**1. move.toml** under **[addresses]** add the address of the package where the function you want to call is defined.

```
[addresses]
package_from_where_you_want_to_call_func = "0x5306f64e312b581766351c07af79c72fcb1cd25147157fdc2f8ad76de9a3fb6a"
```

**2. src/your_module.move**: import the function you want to use.

```
module tutorial::your_module {
    use sui::object::{Self, UID};
    use sui::transfer;
    use sui::tx_context::{Self, TxContext};
    use package_from_where_you_want_to_call_func::desired_module as remote_moduel
    struct ColorObject has key {
        id: UID,
        red: u8,
        green: u8,
        blue: u8,
    }
    remote_module::function_you_want_to_call(....);
    ....

}
```

Here's a sample of a function from bytecode for a [package](https://suiscan.xyz/mainnet/object/0xac176715abe5bcdaae627c5048958bbe320a8474f524674f3278e31af3c8b86b):

```
entry public mint_nft(Arg0: String, Arg1: String, Arg2: vector
<u8>, Arg3: vector<String>, Arg4: vector<String>, Arg5: &mut MintCap<Fuddies>, Arg6: &mut Warehouse<Fuddies>, Arg7: &mut TxContext) 
{
    ...
}
```